# Trying to Create a histogram in R of probability of an occurrence given probabilities

Tags: r

```
pats <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
prob <- c(0.2725, 0.3543, 0.2303, 0.0998, 0.0324, 0.0084, 0.0023)

tab <- data.frame(pats, prob)

h <- hist(pats,
      breaks = pats,
      main = "Probability distribution of the number of patients entering the emergency room during a 1-hour period",
      xlab = "Patients per Hour",
      ylab = "Probability",
      xaxt = "n"
)

axis(1, h$mids, labels = pats, tick = FALSE, padj= -1.5)
```

This is what I have so far any assistance on how to create a histogram with the data frame I have would be great and if there is a better way of doing it that's great too.

Comment: This is no longer a `histogram` try `barplot(prob~pats, tab)`

Comment: Similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62316208/5325862) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22393959/5325862)

Comment: I answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105608/creating-ggplot-histogram/71105764#71105764) yesterday.

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks, barplot is perfect for what I needed.